# Which pseudo-inverse to compute when Inverse is not possible? (No linear solve)

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Let us assume that we have a function, $f(A)=\text{vec}(A^{-1})^\intercal B$, dependent on $A^{-1}$. However, due to some machine-precision limitations, the programming language I'm using cannot invert $A$ even if it has $Det(A)>0$. So, I'm thinking of using a pseudo-inverse, instead.

However, I don't know if there's a 'distance' relationship between the true inverse and the pseudo-inverse. I just know that when there's an inverse, both are equal. But it would be nice, that when the original matrix A and the 'perturbed/truncated' version of A are close, that the pseudo-inverse be close to the inverse of the original...

I'm also looking at pseudo-inverses for which there's a relatively easy and efficient way to compute.

Any suggestions?

Edit: $\dim(A)=DT\times DT$ and $\dim(B)=D^2T^2\times D^2$

Following Federico Poloni's comment, I think I could actually recompute the function above as $$\left[\cdots Tr\left(\text{LinearSolve}\left(A^\intercal, C_i \right) \right) \cdots \right]_{1\times i=1,...,D^2}$$ where $C_i=\text{Reshape}_{DT\times DT}\left(\text{Column}(B,i)\right)$

Comment: what's the action of $\rm{vec}(\cdot)$? is it to reshape the inverse into a one-dimensional (column?) vector?

Comment: @GoHokies Yes. It's an example of a function, among others, which I use with reshapping operations. ;)

Comment: ok, so if $A$ is $N \times N$, then $B$ is an $N^2 \times N^2$ matrix - or a $N^2 \times 1$ vector?

Comment: Is $\det(A)>0$ coming from an exact formula, or is it just a numerical observation? Determinants give no easily readable information on the distance of a matrix from singularity, so in numerical practice they are seldom used.

Comment: Also: you write "no linear solve", but what you have here can be rewritten as linear solves: vectorize (each column of) $B$ to obtain a $N\times N$ matrix $C$, then compute $A^{-1}C$, and the quantity you are looking for is its trace.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for your comments. I'm interested in this last comment of yours. I've added some new info on the dimensions of the matrices. With these dimensions, I don't see how we can convert this problem into a linear solver problem...

Comment: Hum... is what I did correct? @FedericoPoloni

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yes, I think.

Comment: Before thinking of inverting anything, please do consider whether Gaussian elimination does the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pseudoinverses typically will be computed via some truncation procedure to determine the rank, so they are *not* close to the original inverse. Example:
$$A = Q
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ & 10^{-12} \\ & & 10^{-18}
\end{bmatrix}Q^{*}
$$
has exact (pseudo)inverse
$$A^+ = A^{-1} = Q
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ & 10^{12} \\ & & 10^{18}
\end{bmatrix}Q^{*},
$$
but any numerical procedure will have to take a decision on the rank and will likely truncate one or two of those diagonal entries to zero, returning for instance
$$B = Q
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ & 10^{12} \\ & & 0
\end{bmatrix}Q^{*},
$$
or 
$$B = Q
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ & 0 \\ & & 0
\end{bmatrix}Q^{*},
$$
(depending on truncation thresholds), which are not close at all to $A^+$. That is an inherent limitation and I don't think you can overcome it. It's by design: typically, when one writes `pinv(A)` one wants $B$, not $A^{-1}$. If you really want $A^{-1}$, then just use `inv(A)` and forget about the warnings.

But it's probably time to go back to the blackboard, think about what you really need in these edge cases, and see if there is a more stable alternative expression for it. If the exact solution of your problem is *that* ill-conditioned, then probably it's not even what you want at the end of the day.